# Init of SwiftUI View with @Binding optional property seems ambiguous

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

Given my assumptions, from the code below, that:

- `$a` returns a `Binding<Bool>`
- `Binding.constant(a: self.a)` also returns a `Binding<Bool>`

then why does `B(a: Binding<Bool?>)` reject (correctly) the first with `"Cannot convert value of type 'Binding<Bool>' to expected argument type 'Binding<Bool?>'"` but accept the second?

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var a: Bool = false

    var body: some View {
        A(a: $a)
    }
}

struct A : View {
    @Binding var a: Bool

    var body: some View {
            //B(a: $a)
            // ^~~~ 
            // Fails with "Cannot convert value of type 'Binding<Bool>' to expected argument type 'Binding<Bool?>'"       
            B(a: Binding.constant(self.a))
    }
}

struct B : View {
    @Binding var a: Bool?

    var body: some View {

        if a == nil {
            return Text("a is nil")
        } else {
            return Text("a is \(a! ? "true" : "false")")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem is the optional Binding in struct B.   

>  @Binding var a: Bool?

The second solution works because it is wrapped in .constant() which gives it a constant permanent value.(Creates a binding with an immutable value)

Seems like an optional binding is not to be expected, which would make sense.

Comment: This helped me a lot understanding SwiftUI/Bindings
https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/226/

Comment: Thank you Peter Pohlmann and marcprux for your insight. Re-watching the WWDC talk has indeed made me reconsider my use of `@Binding` and `@State`. But my original question stands: why does an init that insists on taking only a `Binding<Bool?>` accept a `Binding<Bool>` when created by `Binding.constant`?

Answer (score 1):

What would you expect to happen to the contents of the non-optional `Bool` held by `A.a` if someone sets the derived optional Bool binding in `B.b` to `nil`? Your workaround of wrapping the `Bool` in a `.constant` works because it prevents that possibility (since a constant binding cannot be changed).

You could alternatively create a derived binding that simply ignores setting `nil` values, like so (note the under-documented "_" prefix for assigning an underlying property wrapper value):

```swift
extension B {
    init(reqA: Binding<Bool>) {
        self._a = Binding<Bool?>(get: { reqA.wrappedValue },
          set: { if let newValue = $0 { reqA.wrappedValue = newValue } })
    }
}
```